# Is there a way of reusing code within the same XCODE Project?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm building an app which has multiple pages which will send data off to an SQL Database.  To make the app more flexible, the address of the database server, the database name, user and password are stored in an SQLite database in the app.

Each page is held in a separate storyboard with it's own swift file with any code needed in it.

I've got some code which reads the information out of the SQLite database, but I'd rather not have to copy and paste it into the swift file for each storyboard, as I think if I want to change something later it means changing it in multiple places.

In PHP, you could use an 'include otherFile.php' to process external files as if they were part of the one that you ran - is there a simple way to do something similar with Xcode?

I've tried to build a framework, but even though I've imported the SQLite framework it doesn't seem to recognise the module when I try and import it?

Comment: show your sample code so that people know why you are stucking

Comment: any classes you write in your project are available to the other parts of your project. No need to use import or include in Swift, unless it's an external framework. You can use a framework, but start with just declaring your Classes in separate files.